# Probabilistic selection from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics, distribution

Does Numpy have any built in functions to randomly select values from a 1D numpy array with a higher weighting given to values at the end of the array? Is there an easier way to do this than defining a skewed distribution and sampling from it to get array indices?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  If that is your goal, then the selections are not actually random.  Furthermore, if more weight is given to the items at the end, then wouldn't the last item always be picked since it has the most weight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give a weight to `np.choice`, as shown:

```
a = np.random.random(100)    # an array to draw from
n = 10                       # number of values to draw
i = np.arange(a.size)        # an array of the index value for weighting
w = np.exp(i/10.)            # higher weights for larger index values
w /= w.sum()                 # weight must be normalized
```

Now, access your values with:

```
np.random.choice(a, size=n, p=w)
```

Clearly you can change your weight array however you want, I did an exponential decay from the end with decay length `10`; increase that decay length for a wider selection:

for `np.exp(i/50.)`:

```
In [38]: np.random.choice(a, size=n, p=w)
Out[38]: array([37, 53, 45, 22, 88, 69, 56, 86, 96, 24])
```

for `np.exp(i)`:

```
In [41]: np.random.choice(a, size=n, p=w)
Out[41]: array([99, 99, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 97, 99, 98])
```

If you only want to be able to get each value once, be sure to set `replace=False`, otherwise you can get the same value several times (especially if it's highly weighted, as in the second example above).  See this example:

```
In [33]: np.random.choice(a, size=n, replace=False, p=w)
Out[33]: array([99, 84, 86, 91, 87, 81, 96, 89, 97, 95])

In [34]: np.random.choice(a, size=n, replace=True, p=w)
Out[34]: array([94, 98, 99, 98, 97, 99, 91, 96, 97, 93])
```

---

My original answer was:

If the form of the distribution doesn't really matter, you could do something like a poisson distribution of indices:

```
idx = np.random.poisson(size=10)
```

Your sample:

```
a[-idx-1]
```